# Attribute a link to another a element

Tags: jquery, attr

I have HTML like this:

```
<div class="post">
  <p><a href="link1">Paralase1 mokew kweis</a></p>
  <p>Kwoie uisye jkui</p>
  <a class="pan">Readmore</a>
</div>

<div class="post">
  <p><a href="link2">Paralase2 mokew kweis</a></p>
  <p>Kwoie uisye jkui</p>
  <a class="pan">Readmore</a>
</div>

<div class="post">
  <p><a href="link3">Paralase3 mokew kweis</a></p>
  <p>Kwoie uisye jkui</p>
  <a class="pan">Readmore</a>
</div>
```

I want element `a` has class name is `pan` will be added link from post title (link1, link2, link3) but also add first word of post title (Paralase1, Paralase2, Paralase3) to have result:

```
<div class="post">
  <p><a href="link1">Paralase1 mokew kweis</a></p>
  <p>Kwoie uisye jkui</p>
  <a class="pan" href="link1#Paralase1">Readmore</a>
</div>

<div class="post">
  <p><a href="link2">Paralase2 mokew kweis</a></p>
  <p>Kwoie uisye jkui</p>
  <a class="pan" href="link2#Paralase2">Readmore</a>
</div>

<div class="post">
  <p><a href="link3">Paralase3 mokew kweis</a></p>
  <p>Kwoie uisye jkui</p>
  <a class="pan" href="link3#Paralase3">Readmore</a>
</div>
```

Comment: And what's a `post title` in this context ?

Comment: @adeneo:they are link1, link2, link3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want the pan to link to the same thing as the paired link?

```
$('.pan').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this),
        $pairedLink = $this.parent().find('a').eq(0),
        desiredLink = $pairedLink.attr('href');

    desiredLink = desiredLink +'#'+ $pairedLink.text().split(' ')[0];

    $this.attr('href', desiredLink);
});
```

It would be an easier selector if the first link had a class.

Including a fiddle reference: https://jsfiddle.net/bqz7zmhf/1/

Comment: Thank you. I understand your way. I hope I can follow it.

Comment: Is it possible to have list of links results like: link1#Paralase1, link2#Paralase2, link3#Paralase3. It means it also add first word of post title into link.

Comment: Thank you but Paralase1, Paralase2, Paralase3 are different words not index. just for example.

Comment: Hi Taplar. they are different words (The first word of each title).

Comment: Sorry for confusing but result is great. Thank you very much and Happy new year.

Answer (score 1):

Can bind a simple click handler to trigger click on other link

```
$('.pan').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().find('a:first').click();
});
```

Or loop through all posts and add the href.

```
$('a.pan').attr('href',function(){
    return $(this).parent().find('a:first').attr('href');
});
```

Comment: I have modified question, can you give me suggestion for new update?

Comment: You just want the first word? Expected results not clear

Comment: Yes. first word of each title. I want it appear after link#. It is my purpose but your result not worked as my expects.

Comment: Why do you need the initial link added to "read more" in the first place? If all you want is a hash just use that. You should be doing more at server to simplify this. If the ID exists for the hash created at server why aren't you adding it to the links when they are created?